# Javascript - strip out occurrences of u' in JSON string, parse is returning unexpected token

Tags: javascript, python, regex, json

I have a textfield in a database that contains the results of a python `json.dumps(list_instance)` operation.  As such, the internal fields have a `u'` prefix, and break the browser's `JSON.parse()` function.

An example of the JSON string is

```
"density": "{u'Penobscot': 40.75222856500098, u'Sagadahoc': 
  122.27083333333333, u'Lincoln': 67.97977755308392, u'Kennebec': 
  123.12237174095878, u'Waldo': 48.02117802779616, u'Cumberland':  
  288.9285325791363, u'Piscataquis': 3.9373586457405247, u'Hancock': 
  30.698239582715903, u'Washington': 12.368718341168325, u'Aroostook': 
  10.827378163074039, u'York': 183.47612497543722, u'Franklin':  
  16.89330963710371, u'Oxford': 25.171240748402518, u'Somerset': 
  12.425648288323485, u'Knox': 108.48302300109529, u'Androscoggin': 
  208.75502815768303}"
```

What I'd like to do is replace those occurrences of `u'` with a `'`(single-quote).  I've tried

```
function renderValues(data){
   var pop = JSON.parse(data.density.replace(/u'/g, "'"));
}
```

but I'm always getting a `unexpected token '` exception.  Since many of the possible key fields may contain a `u`, it is not feasable to just delete that character.  How can I find all instances of `u'` and replace with `'` without getting the exception?

Comment: Aren't you missing outermost  `{ and }` from JOSN string?

Comment: @anubhava, no.  That is a sample from a serialized return from a Django model.  Rather than do an entire data dump, I just showed a sample of the overall data format.

Comment: Well in that case there is no error when I tried above JSON string with your code.

Comment: @anubhava, what browser did you check it with?  I'm using chrome 32 on ubuntu.  It turns out that replacing the single quotes with double quotes solved the problem.

Comment: I tested on chrome, can produce jsfiddle also.

Comment: The value for density is a plain string that looks a little bit like a JSON string, but it is not. Fix the problem in the server and not in the client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated solution: `replace(/u'/g, "'"));` => `replace(/u'(?=[^:]+')/g, "'"));`.

Tested with the following:

`"{u'Penobscot': 40.75222856500098, u'Sagadahoc': 122.27083333333333, u'Lincoln': 67.97977755308392, u'Kennebec': 123.12237174095878, u'Waldo': 48.02117802779616, u'Cumberland': 288.9285325791363, u'Piscataquis': 3.9373586457405247, u'Hancock': 30.698239582715903, u'Timbuktu': 12.368718341168325, u'Aroostook': 10.827378163074039, u'York': 183.47612497543722, u'Franklin': 16.89330963710371, u'Oxford': 25.171240748402518, u'Somerset': 12.425648288323485, u'Knox': 108.48302300109529, u'Androscoggin': 208.75502815768303}".replace(/u'(?=[^:]+')/g, "'");`

results in:

`"{'Penobscot': 40.75222856500098, 'Sagadahoc': 122.27083333333333, 'Lincoln': 67.97977755308392, 'Kennebec': 123.12237174095878, 'Waldo': 48.02117802779616, 'Cumberland': 288.9285325791363, 'Piscataquis': 3.9373586457405247, 'Hancock': 30.698239582715903, 'Timbuktu': 12.368718341168325, 'Aroostook': 10.827378163074039, 'York': 183.47612497543722, 'Franklin': 16.89330963710371, 'Oxford': 25.171240748402518, 'Somerset': 12.425648288323485, 'Knox': 108.48302300109529, 'Androscoggin': 208.75502815768303}"`

Comment: If a car leaks oil in your garage, it is better to the leak rather than put a bucket underneath it.

Comment: I meant, it is better to fix the leak... I cant edit anymore.

Comment: This is not a good solution because it will remove the trailing u in any string, for example if your string is `u'Timbuktu'` then it will end up as `'Timbukt'`.  As mentioned elsewhere, the input displayed by the user is not JSON and the generation needs to be fixed rather than attempting band-aids such as the suggested solution.

Comment: You'd also get things like `"Washington'` with non-matching quote characters.

Comment: It's a sloppy solution for a problem that is somewhere else. Basically, treating the symptomps instead of the root cause. Perfect recipe for failing.

Comment: it seems some strings are u" and not u' when they contain single quotes... so one might add a second phase with replace(/u"/g, "\""));

Answer (score 5):

The accepted solution is wrong. Your code fails because that string is not valid JSON. Fixing the pseudo-JSON string by replacing it is wrong.

What you have to do is fix the python code that is producing that broken JSON string, which I am pretty sure it is a str() or unicode() where there should be nothing. What you have as a value for the key "density" is a string instead of a dictionary, and therefore, python returns you something like the following:

```
{"density": "a string that looks like JSON but it is in fact a string reprensentation of a dictionary"}
```

The function `json.dumps` will return you always valid JSON strings.

Fix that and you will not have to hack around with filthy string replacements or whatever.

**EDIT**

Check the following snippet out. There you can see that the u'...' is just the python readable-representation of a unicode object, and has nothing to do whatsoever with a JSON serialization.

```
>>> import json
>>> data = {u'name': u'Manuel', u'age': 26}
>>> print data
{u'age': 26, u'name': u'Manuel'}  # this is the python representation of a dictionary
>>> print json.dumps(data)
{"age": 26, "name": "Manuel"} # this is a valid JSON string
```

That JSON is not properly formed, as easy as that.

Comment: You never know, he could potentially not have access to the server generating the JSON, which would explain the reason for his method.

Comment: I accepted the answer by @tenub because it allowed me to take care of the issue without having to go into the data storage.  The thing you are missing is the fact that the dict keys themselves are prefixed with `u`, and are therefore untouched by any of `json.dumps()` actions.

Comment: That u'..' is just the python representation for a unicode object, which is completely irrelevant as to the JSON serialization of the dictionary. Neither keys nor values are actually prefixed by "u".

Answer (score 0):

a little bit old in the answer but if there is no way to change or access the server response try with:

```
var strExample = {'att1':u'something with u'};

strExample.replace(/u'[\}|\,]/g, "ç'").replace(/u'/g, "'").replace(/ç'/g, "u'");

//{'att1':'something with u'};
```

The first replace will handle the u' that are in the trailing part of the string in the object changing it to 'ç' character

then removing the u from the phyton unicode and finally change it to u' like the original

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and made this regex that found all of the u's even if the values had them too.

```
replace(/(?!\s|:)((u)(?='))/g, "")
```

The accepted answer, I found, missed these occurrences.

I know the OP's doesn't have 'u' for the values and only for keys but thought this may be useful too :)